# Spring swagger @ApiParam annotation hides a method

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I'm facing with issue that if I mark any param inside method signature with swagger's `@ApiParam` annotation, then I don't see this method on address /swagger-ui.html

Examples:

```
@GetMapping
@ApiOperation(value = "Get magazines by type")
public List<Magazine> getMagazines(@RequestParam @NotNull String type) {
    List<Magazine> response = service.getMagazines(type);
    return response;
    }
```

In such case if I go to the localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html I will see this method inside controller
[image]

But if the method has `@ApiParam` annotation, it's just not shown on swagger

```
@GetMapping
@ApiOperation(value = "Get magazines by type")
public List<Magazine> getMagazines(@ApiParam(defaultValue = "TEST") @RequestParam @NotNull String type) {
    List<Magazine> response = service.getMagazines(type);
    return response;
}
```

[image]

Any ideas why it may happen?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of implementations of the swagger specification out there. I'm using the following one

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>


  @GetMapping
  @ApiOperation(value = "Get magazines by type") 
  public List<Magazine>getMagazines(@ApiParam(defaultValue = "TEST")  @RequestParam String type) {
    List<Magazine> response = service.getMagazines(type);
    return response;
  }
```

I'm not facing any issue as mentioned by you. Perhaps there might be an issue with the implementation you're using.
[image]